# Google App Engine Shared Memcache is having short life span

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

I realize the shared memcache in Google App Engine, can only hold the key-value for a very short period. I have perform the following call for 20 times, at different timestamp.

```
_MEMCACHE_DURATION = 14*24*60*60
memcache.add(email, user_timestamp, _MEMCACHE_DURATION)
```

My expectation is, the key-value will last for 14 days. However, I find out the oldest item age is "1 hr 42 min"

When I look at documentation, I thought that valid time is up to 1 month : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/functions#Client_add

I was wondering, is such behavior correct?

Comment: You can pay for a reserved memcache which I assume will hold records for however long is desired. Not actually used it yet myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 hour 42 minutes is a substantial improvement from when I last measured it (which was then a substantial improvement over the time before).

Unless you're paying for reserved memcache, it's a shared resource. It's best to think of it as a short-term cache, where short-term is measured in minutes. A good use of such caching is to improve performance across requests within a session.

Answer (score 2):

read about the difference between shared and paid memcache in the official docs. shared comes with no guarantees about how long the data will remain there.

Official documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/developers-console/#memcache

Best practices for memcache: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/best-practices-for-app-engine-memcache

Answer (score 2):

You should typically not make assumptions about the lifespan of a memcache entry since the very next request may end up not finding the entry which can **dissapear at any time** for various reasons: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/#Python_How_cached_data_expires (zero lifespan if you want).

I'd interpret the "(up to 1 month)" note as a **maximum** lifespan.

Comment: can you link to the docs that mention this? I believe memcached (at least for appengine) does not have the issue you mention. either the item is or isnt there regadless of which instance handles it. appengine doesnt have instances in mixed countries.

Comment: I admit, my answer was based on my mental-crutch representation of the system, built also from bits and pieces (docs don't always cover everything :) While the crutch itself serves well (I was using the same crutch for datastore eventual consistency), its reasoning was in fact technically incorrect for memcache. This discussion explains it better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252327. I'll correct the answer.